# How to access API reference from Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm tired of switching between Xcode and the browser to check iPhone API reference from Apple web site. Any better way to to it directly from Xcode ? Ideally I'd like to select a word and search for it in the API reference automatically.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a copy of the API reference in your local machine already. Check Help -> Developer Documentation.

You can also use "Opt + Double click" on a word to get quick help, "Cmd + Opt + Double click" to get detailed doc.